# Would like to pageYoffset

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to know a thing and for sure you have to solution, because isn't success.

I would like to scroll at 500px for example a element div appears on left side. Ok the HTML/CSS structure is ok ! But for the JS humm not worked.!

You can see this example :

HTML:

```
<div class="left"></div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

body {
  height: 200vh;
}

.left {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 150%;
  transform: translateX(-300px);
  transition: 1s;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var divLis = document.querySelector(".left");

window.addEventListener("scroll", function (e) {

    if(window.pageYOffset > 500) {
        console.log(window.pageYOffset)
        divLis.style.transform = "translateX(0)";
    }

})
```

When the page is > 500px, after that the element is appear. But isn't ok for me, i would like == 500px you have a solution for me ?

PLEASE : No JQuery

Comment: Use .scrollTop? http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_scrolltop.asp

Comment: if(divLis.scrollTop === 500) {
            console.log(divLis.scrollTop)
            divLis.style.transform = "translateX(0)";
        }
Not work.. I try this before

Comment: You are missing ; after console.log()

Comment: I use that because I want to this div element appear at 500px when the user scrolling, you understand ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `window.scrollY` or `document.body.scrollTop`

```js
var divLis = document.querySelector(".left");

window.addEventListener("scroll", function(e) {
  var scrollTop = document.body.scrollTop;
  //var scrollTop = window.scrollY;
  //console.log(scrollTop);
  if (scrollTop > 500) {
    divLis.style.transform = "translateX(0)";
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

body {
  height: 500vh;
}

.left {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 150%;
  transform: translateX(-300px);
  transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">left</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. 
Isn't possible to make a fixe result like scrollTop === 500 ?? Why ?

Comment: @KolaCaine it is. Try setting that, then scrolling to 500 slowly. Probably helps if you enable a console.log so you know when you're near 500.

Comment: Ok I see that. :) Thank you